# Open image on the current page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm trying to make a gallery and when the user click on a picture I want it to open on top of everything in it's original size.

I only have experience with html and css right now but willing to give JS and jQuery etc a try if necessary. Thank you in advance!

(I didn't provide any code since I don't have a problem with it)

Comment: You should always provide code of things you tried before posting the question and links of guides you followed to reach that code.

Comment: create a div at the top of all then display image on that div

Comment: Do you really want to do this from scratch? I mean there are lots of plugin solutions for this, but it depends on your requirements. Plugins often come with more code than you may need.

Comment: Since you didn't provide any source code, could you provide your attempts? Also displaying source code is relevant for us to see where you want the image to display and see the ids/classes given to the elements you have. Without your source code we will have to write this from scratch. How many do you think will do that?

Comment: search for fancybox or shadowbox on the web you'll find lots of not to complicated options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this might help you [Shadow Box](http://www.shadowbox-js.com/)

See the images.

Update:

[fancybox demo](http://fancybox.net/)

Comment: This (ShadowBox) worked perfectly! Had a small problem at first as I thought it wanted me to put the whole shadowbox folder with my project but it was only it's content- Thank you very much!

Comment: Pleasure always mate :)